# Get all changes with filenames for a particular user

Tags: perforce

Is it possible to get the filename for all changelists for a particular user. Right now I can only get the list of changes from a particular user

```
p4 changes -s submitted -u UserX
```

I know it is possible to do it using p4 describe, however how do I make it work on all the files by a particular User

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p4 -Ztag -F @=%change% changes -s submitted -u UserX | p4 -x - files`

Comment: Thanks. Just had a question about why @= is needed before piping it to p4 files. Also what does "p4 -x -" mean? What is the "-x" and "- " for

Comment: https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/#CmdRef/filespecs.html?Highlight=@=
https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/#CmdRef/global.options.html?Highlight=argfile
See the highlighted terms on those pages (@= and -x argfile)

Comment: Great. Thanks. Wasn't even aware about these options.